# Passed parameter can be explicit 'undefined' or not passed

Tags: javascript

I need following:

```
function(arg) {
  if (undefined was passed explicitly)
     //case 1
  if (no parameter was passed)
    // case 2
}
```

Is that possible?
Next statements don't make difference between the cases:

```
typeof args === 'undefined'
args === undefined
args === null
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example of what is it that you want it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use javascript [rest or spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) ... to define function arguments.

```js
function call(...args){
 if(args.length == 0)
  {
    console.log("no args passed");
  }
  else if(args[0] == undefined || args[0] == 'undefined'){
    console.log("args is undefined");
  }
  else 
  {
  console.log(args);
  }
}

call(undefined);
call('undefined');
call(null)
call(1,2,4);
call();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

```
function test(...args) {
  if (args.length && typeof args[0] === 'undefined') {
    console.log('explicitly undefined');
  } else {
    console.log('just undefined');
  }
}
```

The spread operator will expand any passed arguments into an array. If the array length is zero, nothing was passed, and therefore `undefined` is implicit. If there *is* an array length, then we can explicitly check for its type.